# Sortable not working in Firefox but every other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using this example (http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/saving-state-for-collapsible-drag-drop-panels/) in my asp.net application. I have the sortable working in every browser other than Firefox, for some reason it triggers the event but never go into the code.

```
    $('.column').sortable({
        connectWith: '.column',
        handle: 'h2',
        cursor: 'move',
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        opacity: 0.4,
        start: function (event, ui) {
            //Firefox, Safari/Chrome fire click event after drag is complete, fix for that  
            if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.safari)
                $(ui.item).find('.dragbox-content').toggle();
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.css({ 'top': '0', 'left': '0' }); //Opera fix  
                updateWidgetData();
        }
        })
.disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: This isn't a complete, executable example. Maybe http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Firefox doesn't accept functions with the wrong number of parameters as event functions. This is according to the standard so you should comply. Try this:

```
start: function (event) {
```

The `ui` parameter cannot follow the event to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for using jQuery sortable for all Chrome &  Firefox:

You must delete the line `$(#sortable).disableSelection();` in jQuery Sortable code. (ref: [Sortable | jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/))

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });    
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

i have done

```
$("#stores-container").sortable({

    stop: function(event, ui) {

        textareaID = $(ui.item).find(' textarea').attr('id');

        textareaVal=$(ui.item).find(' textarea').val();

        editorID=$(ui.item).find('.mce-container').attr('id');

        $( "#"+editorID ).remove();

        $('#'+textareaID).show();
        tinymce.init({selector: '#'+textareaID});
    }

});
```